# Start Background Task using ASP.Net Core Middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, middleware

I'm attempting to run an asynchronous task when loading a page in ASP.Net Core, i.e., I want the task to run as soon as the user routes to the page but for the page to be displayed before the task has completed. It seems that with ASP.Net core you use middleware to perform such tasks. So I attempted to add the following to `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

// Other configurations here
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("PageWithAsyncTask"))
                {
                    var serviceWithAsyncTask = serviceProvider.GetService<IMyService>();
                    await serviceWithAsyncTask .DoAsync();
                }
                await next.Invoke();
            });

app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

}
```

The problem with the above is that there is a delay in the page loading until `DoAsync` has complete since we don't call `next.Invoke()` until `DoAsync` is complete. How do I correctly implement the above such that `next.Invoke()` is called immediately after I've got `DoAsync` running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.NET was not designed for background tasks. I *strongly* recommend using a proper architecture, such as Azure Functions / WebJobs / Worker Roles / Win32 services / etc, with a reliable queue (Azure queues / MSMQ / etc) for the ASP.NET app to talk to its service.

However, if you *really* want to - and are willing to accept the risks (specifically, that your work may be aborted), then you can use [`IApplicationLifetime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iapplicationlifetime).

Comment: *Asp.Net Web API application which uses Quartz.Net for scheduling jobs*  out of this scope rigth?

Comment: @ibubi: Quartz.Net and HangFire each have their own drawbacks; I consider them as alternatives to `IApplicationLifetime`.

Comment: Thank you but, I don't understand, hundreds of Asp.net&Quartz.Net or Hangfire implementation tutorials all around adviced, could you please refer a brief document explains why we should avoid using these two or our custom libraries in Asp.Net?

Comment: @ibubi I've never used Quartz.NET. But at least with Hangfire, you need to ensure that your web application stays running constantly yourself. And now it's taking up resources that your website could be using, and now you can't scale it separately from your website. That's all of course assuming you host Hangfire within your web application project. I've had great success hosting Hangfire as a separate console application I run as a Windows service with TopShelf - that eliminates the drawbacks but means you need a separate project to deploy.

Comment: @ibubi: I recommend asking your own question. That's a lot to talk about in answer comments.

Answer (score 16):

In ASP.NET Core 2 the IHostedService is designed to run your background tasks. 
Register the IHostedService as Singleton and it is automatically started at startup:

[implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/)

[asp-net-core-background-processing](https://thinkrethink.net/2018/02/21/asp-net-core-background-processing/)

Answer (score 6):

Since **Asp.Net core 2.1** to use background tasks it is very convenient to implement `IHostedService` by  deriving from the [`BackgroundService`](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs) base class. Here is the sample taken from [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/samples/GenericHostSample/MyServiceA.cs):

```
public class MyServiceA : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyServiceA is starting.");

        stoppingToken.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("MyServiceA is stopping."));

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MyServiceA is doing background work.");

            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), stoppingToken);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("MyServiceA background task is stopping.");
    }
}
```

Then just register it in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, MyServiceA>();
```

And as Stephen Cleary noted `Asp.Net` application may not be the best place for background tasks (e.g. when app is hosted in IIS it can be shut down because of app pool recycles), but for some scenarios it can be applied very well.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
await serviceWithAsyncTask .DoAsync();
```

you could use

```
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
       SomeMethod();
   });
```

In this approach an additional thread will be used from the thread pool which is of course a requirement if you want the code to run on a thread other than the main thread :-)

Any code placed after this block will run immediately.  Also note that if your web server process (kestral) is recycled by IIS or whatever reverse proxy you are using then your background worker will be aborted immediately.   So your background worker needs to be written defensively with this in mind.

Also please note that `SomeMethod()` is not itself an `async` method.  But it's being called from a background thread so it's running asyncronously (i.e. independent of the main thread.)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at HangFire for managing background processing, works great in .Net Core: https://www.hangfire.io/