# ASP.NET Core - Calling Controller HTTP Endpoints always leads to 'Bad Request'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have auto-generated a controller which handles creation / insertion / deletion of `GearComponent` (my custom class). This `POST` method for example handles the insertion of a `GearComponent`, later adding the correct primary key `id` from the database:

```
// POST: api/GearComponents
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostGearComponent([FromBody] GearComponent gearComponent)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return new BadRequestObjectResult(
            ModelState.Values
                .SelectMany(e => e.Errors)
                .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
    }

    _context.GearComponents.Add(gearComponent);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetGearComponent", new { id = gearComponent.Id }, gearComponent);
}
```

I want to continously write to the database while the ASP.NET Core 2.1 application is running (it is a "WebCrawler"-Thing). [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367609/start-background-task-using-asp-net-core-middleware) lead me to [this thread](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/) of how to implement a `BackgroundService` and register it on startup.

This is my service (it is just inserting dummy data):

```
public class WebCrawlerService : BackgroundService
{

    private readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    private readonly string requestUrl = "https://localhost:44377/api/controller/";

    public WebCrawlerService() { }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new GearComponent("Name", "Description", "08.12.2018")));
            var result = client.PostAsync(requestUrl, httpContent);
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

While inserting the exact same `GearComponent` (the JSON-String is the same) with `Postman` works fine:

[image]

I always get

> 400 Bad Request

from this `result` (see `WebCrawlerService`):

```
var result = client.PostAsync(requestUrl, httpContent);
```

Why? Thanks to @Haldo it is working now:

```
var httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new GearComponent("Name", "Description", "08.12.2018")), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: What headers are you using? It needs `application/json` as content type.

Comment: @Haldo Thanks, it is working now!